# Comparing elements of two strings

Tags: string, vba, excel, compare

I've developed the following code to compare two cells (strings) in columns A and D and write down the D cell value in the corresponding B cell if a partial match is found.

```
Sub CompareAndGuess()
Dim strLen, aux As Integer
Dim max1, max2 As Long
Dim str As String

Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
max1 = ActiveCell.Row
Range("D1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
max2 = ActiveCell.Row

For a = 2 To max1
    str = Cells(a, 1)
    str = StrConv(str, vbUpperCase)
    strLen = Len(str)
    aux = strLen

    For l = 3 To strLen
         For d = 2 To max2
             If Cells(d, 4) = Left(str, aux) Then
                Cells(a, 2) = Cells(d, 4)
                Exit For
            ElseIf Cells(d, 4) = Right(str, aux) Then
                Cells(a, 2) = Cells(d, 4)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next d

        aux = aux - 1
        If Cells(a, 2) <> "" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next l
     Cells(a, 2).Select
Next a
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me find where is the problem because when I run it the code only guesses right one row out of 50 whereas it should match at least 40 or so.

Please, I really can't find the error in there. Feel free to propose another solution to my problem if you want.

A sample of the data I'm analysing is:
Names with Typos:-

```
Jatiuca
Pajuara
Poco
Santa Luzia
Pajucara
Domingos Acacio
Jaragua
Stella Maris
P Verde
Tabuleiro dos Martin
Gruta Lourdes
Brasilia
Centro Historico
Monumento
Tabuleiro dos Martins
```

Names with Typos to be searched on this list:-

```
JARAGUÁ
TABULEIRO DO MARTINS
CENTRO
BRASÍLIA
CACIMBAS
JATIÚCA
CAITITUS
PAJUÇARA
CANAÃ
PONTA VERDE
CANAFÍSTULA
POÇO
CAPIATÃ
CAVACO
SANTA LÚCIA
```

Comment: VB has the `InStr` function which might be of interest here...

Comment: Yes I also thought on that method and thank you for the remimder. I'll give it a try but still I would like to know what is wrong in my code...

Comment: Because of similarity with 1 (one)? If so, good point. Thank you!

Comment: `Instr(Start:=1, "Cell Value", "Text to find", vbTextCompare)` will return Zero since "Text to find" is not in "Cell Value". If found, it returns on the n'th character that the match is found.

Comment: Can you provide any sample data with expected outcomes

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But that wasn't the problem in here. If anyone could help me...
I've tried with the InStr function and it kinda works, not the way I like it because I don't want to find a middle substring, just a left-ended or a right-ended. For example, with InStr I would find "amp" in "example" but with the method I developed I wouldn't (this is good for preventing error matches)

Comment: I believe I found the error (after 1~1.5 hours). It is on the "Cells(d, 4)". I'm comparing an half word with a full word in there...
I'll try to fix it now. Thanks for the help anyway guys. If anywone wants to porpose a solution, feel free to do it.

Comment: For the semi-words starting from left, I've managed to do it with "If InStr(1, Cells(d, 4), Left(str, aux) = 1 Then".
for the semi-words starting from right, any guess?

Comment: Which words are you expecting to find in your sample data?

Comment: Thank you pnuts but I was looking for a VBA solution. Really thanks.
Graham Anderson, I'm expecting that the code searches the "Names with typos" on the second list and return the name on the second list if a match is found.

Comment: For the "from right to left" search I've came with this method: "If InStr(Cells(d, 4), Right(str, aux)) > 0 And InStr(Cells(d, 4), Right(str, aux)) + aux - 1 = strLen Then" but it isn't working properly. Any help?

Comment: Are you expecting JARAGUÁ and Jaragua to be a match or BRASÍLIA and Brasilia? At present they will not match because of the accented letters Á and Í. In your sample your code appears to only find CENTRO. Is this what you expect or should it match more?

Comment: Guys, I've found the right way to do it. I'll post here just to show you all and anyone who googles this. Thank you all again! Although I figured the method by myself you were really useful (specially with the "InStr" tip!!!)

Comment: I think you would have much better luck if you first trested that the length of the 2 words was the same, then did a character by character test in order testing every letter in order from start to finish and then if a high enough percentage of the word matches (1 incorrect letter out of 10) then you do the replace

Answer (score 3):

I've found the right way to do it with everyone's help.
Here it is:

```
        If InStr(1, Cells(d, 4), Left(str, aux)) = 1 Then
            Cells(a, 2) = Cells(d, 4)
            Exit For
        ElseIf InStr(Cells(d, 4), Right(str, aux)) + strLen - aux = strLen Then
            Cells(a, 2) = Cells(d, 4)
            Exit For
        End If
```

Comment: This seems incredibly unreliable, am I wrong or will this replace any word that contains the first or last 3 letters of a word in the list? Why even both with looping the different length why not just do a single loop of the first and last 3 letters only?

Comment: This seems to not be functioning always in fact. I don't search only for 3 because finding 4, 5, 6, etc. sequence letters is better than finding only 3 where two or more words may have those 3 but not those 4, 5, 6, etc.

Comment: but it might repace the wrong words with the wrong words because it DOES contain the 3 even though that names are much different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you solved the problem yourself using the InStr function. The reason your code wasn't working well was because you were comparing shortened versions of the names with full length versions. Modifying your earlier code with the following would have found a lot more matches.

```
            If Left(Cells(d, 4), aux) = Left(str, aux) Then
                Cells(a, 2) = Cells(d, 4)
                Exit For
            ElseIf Right(Cells(d, 4), aux) = Right(str, aux) Then
                Cells(a, 2) = Cells(d, 4)
                Exit For
            End If
```

Comment: I believe this would only work if both words with typos and without typos have the same lenght. What doesn't hapen. Thanks anyway

Comment: @BrunoMartins it would only need to compare the beginings or ends of words, tried it on your sample data and it found 10 matches, but not POÇO.

Comment: I'm at the moment using something similar to what you posted here but without the "aux" on the left side of each comparisson and with a different variable so I run all combinations possibles to find the best match.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely ***UNTESTED***

I will rewrite tomorrow, and clean it up but this is the basic way to REALLY know you are matching the correct words. It may take a little longer, and i will speed it up A LOT tomorrow but for now this is the closet way to test the words for validity

```
'Go through all possibly typod words
For each rngTestCell in Range("yourlist")

   'For each possibly typod word test if against every correct value
    For each rngCorrectedValue in Range("ListOfCorrectValues")

        'start by testing length to weed out most values quick
        'Test any words that are within 3 letters of each other, can be less
        'could add a tet for first and last letters match also before starting 
        'to match every letter also, just a top level weeding of words
        If (Len(rngTestCell) - Len(rngCorrectedValue)) < 3 Then

           'loop each letter in the words for match keep a record of how many are matched
           for i = 1 to Len(rngTestCell)

                If rngTestCell.Character(i,1) = rngCorrectedValue.Characters(i,1) Then
                     NumberOfMatches = NumberOfMatches + 1
                End If

            next i

            'if enough of the letters match replace the word, this will need updating because
            'i feel using a ratio of more then 10% of the words match then replace
            'but for now if more then 2 letters don't match then it isn't a match
            If (Len(rngTestCell) - NumberOfMatches) > 2 Then 'Less then 2 letters are different
                rngTestCell.Offset(,1).Value = rngCorrectedValue.Value
                Exit Loop
            End If

        End If

    Next rngCorrectedValues

Next rngTestCell
```

Comment: Probably a modified version of the Smith-Waterman algorithm optimised for matching language would be the best way to go? You could probably use 1 for each matched character and -1 for each unmatched, insertion or delete. Maybe over-engineering the solution though.

Comment: @GrahamAnderson This was done really fast more of a proof of concept but as of now this is the only answer that won't replace `CANAFISTULA` with `CANAÃ`,  eventhough `CANAFISTULA` should be replaced with `CANAFÍSTULA`, further more if the correct word `CANAFÍSTULA` was in the list it would be replaced with `CANAÃ` this example won't have that fault. The point of this is to make sure not to replacing things incorrectly. I don't see how that is over-engineering anything, if there is a simpler way to get the same results then yes this would be but this was the simplest I could think of.

Comment: Neither my method nor I suspect Bruno's would replace CANAFISTULA with CANAÃ when the correct name CANAFÍSTULA is in the correct list, this is because the loop terminates after the 1st (and hence longest) match. I do think your method is the more robust. Sorry for any offence caused by the over engineering remark, I meant it for the consideration of using a Smith-Waterman type algorithm. These are normally used to align protein or nucleic acid sequences. It would test every possible  full/partial match between each pair of strings and as such could be considered a bit much.